# How to define a function having format fn : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> unit

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I need to write a function printGenList that take a function f and a list l and applies f on every element of l recursively.

I tried this -

```
fun printGenList (f (int)list):unit =
  ( f(HD list);   printGenList (f) (TL list) );
```

I could do the same for an infinite list but unable to get it for definite list.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

- The `(int)` on the first line shouldn't be there.
- `HD` / `TL` should be `hd` / `tl`.
- You need to handle the case where `list` is `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambiguous. If I have understood you correctly, you want a function that takes a list, applies a function to each element and prints the result?

You can do that with map, providing that the output of f is printable:

```
fun printGenList f xs = map (fn x => print (f x)) xs
```

Another way to do it with explicit recursion would be:

```
fun printGenList f [] = ()
  | printGenList f (x::xs) = print (f x); printGenList f xs
```

Yet another way to do it (using a case statement and the List.hd and List.tl functions, which many people on this site seem to be fond of):

```
fun printGenList f xs = case xs of
                          [] => ()
                        | xs => print (f (hd xs)); printGenList f (tl xs)
```

I don't know how far you are in your understanding of higherorder-functions, but I would advise you to get a grasp of them as quickly as possible since they are one of your most powerful tools in this language. I'm not too crazy about the last solution either, since I think the hd and tl functions only obscure the meaning of the code, as opposed to clarifying it.

If I misunderstood your question and the function is not supposed to explicitly print itself, you can do something like this:

```
fun printGenList f:('a -> unit) xs = *code*
```

With this function you can call any ('a -> unit) function, for example `` `printGenList print xs ``, which would just print out the entire list.